# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "sich behaupten" und "sich durchsetzen"?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

Momentan tue ich mich schwer mit dem Unterschied zwischen "sich behaupten" und "sich durchsetzen". In English, werden die beiden irgendwie als "assert oneself" übersetzt, aber ich habe das Gefühl, es besteht ein irgendwo ein Unterschied.

Was ich davon verstehe: wenn man sich durchsetzt, dann gewinnt man an Boden. Wenn man sich behauptet, dann verliert man kein Boden. Zum Beispiel, wären die folgenden Sätze richtig:

1. Michael asserted himself boldly in his new job/position. Michael hat sich kühn in seiner neuen Position behauptet.
2. He prevailed in the debate, because he held his ground. Er hat sich in der Debatte durchgesetzt, weil er sich behauptet hat.

Comment: I find your way to discern the meaning of the two verbs very convincing (Boden gewinnen vs. halten). The only thing I would remark is that the use of *kühn* is a little bit odd here. The word would typically be used in fairy tails or stories about medievel knights, less typically in context of todays work environment. But that's just a stylistic thing.

Comment: Christian: Thank you! I wanted to say "bold", as in, he "took a stand". Could you suggest another word?

Answer (score 8):

*Sich behaupten* bedeutet, dass der Kopf (*das Haupt*) über Wasser oder auf dem Halse bleibt. Der-/diejenige *lässt sich nicht unterkriegen* und *besteht*. Es handelt sich also um ein erfolgreiches **defensives** Handeln.

*Sich durchsetzen* bedeutet hingegen, dass man erfolgreich **offensiv** handelt, indem man *einen Stich setzt*, *durch* ein Hindernis hindurch.

Comment: Danke!!! Sind meine Beispielsätze richtig?

Comment: *Kühn* wird eher mit draufgängerischem, also offensivem Verhalten in Verbindung gebracht. Eine *kühne These* ist zum Beispiel eine gewagte, leicht angreifbare These. Leicht angreifbar wird man dadurch, dass man selbst angreift, also eben gerade nicht defensiv agiert.

Comment: *Er hat sich in der Debatte durchgesetzt, weil er sich behauptet hat.* passt ebenfalls nicht so gut, weil es offensiven Erfolg mit einem defensiven Verhalten begründet. Da fehlt eine Erklärung: *Er hat sich in der Debatte **letztendlich doch** durchgesetzt, **nachdem** er sich lange **nur** behauptet hatte.*

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct.

"sich behaupten" means you are on top (of whatever) are challenged, and defeat (in whichever way) the challenger.

"sich durchsetzen" means for example that you win an argument by asserting your opinion over the others (taking part in the argument)

Comment: Vielen Dank! Das war sehr hilfreich für mich. Kannst du mir sagen, ob meine Beispielsätze Sinn machen?

Comment: @Mark Your first sentence does make sense. The second one does too. (it sounds a bit weird to me but it definitely does make sense)